# How to debug/step through a plain Mono C# class library project in Xamarin Studio 2

Tags: c#, macos, debugging, mono, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Studio (2.0) and have created a basic C# class library project and a C# console project.  I have set the console project as the startup project and added a reference to the class library project, which contains a method that gets called from the console project--pretty generic setup.

The application functionally works as expected, however when I set breakpoints, none of them get triggered...just blows past them.  I have tried this both in the class library as well as the calling method in the console application.

Does Xamarin Studio support step-through debugging of standard Mono console and class library projects?  If so, what do I need to do to set up my environment to get this to work?  Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to tag osx, as xamarin-studio is available on both Windows and OSX.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the latest updates for Xamarin Studio and the Mono Framework MDK and attempted to hit a breakpoint in the debugger, and it works. Not certain if that specifically fixed the issue, but things seem to be working now.

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but I guess the MDK contains debugging symbols which are not available in MRE. So on Mac, you should always install MDK so as to set up the development environment.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for the info.  I am relatively new to developing on Mac and I simply trusted that the original install covered all the necessary dependencies.